# Is there a way to partially increment up and down through a large array via a button?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am a very green programmer but I'm trying to build an application that takes a text from a website (for the app I'm using gutenburg.org's open ebook catalog) and displays the story in bites of 10 indexes at a time in a div to make the story easier to read for those with ADD. When the reader finishes the line and clicks next, the next 10 indexes of the array will be displayed. But I'm stuck on how to increment up to the next ten indexes from the initial array.splice(0,10). Is this even possible? Heres my code.

```
HTML:
<input type="text" id="url" style="width: 400px">
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Get JSON">

Javscript:
   $(function() {
        $( '#service' ).on( 'change', function(){
            $( '#url' ).val( $( this ).val() );
        });

        //angular.module('exampleApp')
        $( '#url' ).val( $( '#service' ).val() );

        $( '#btn' ).click(function(){
            var url = $( '#url' ).val()

            $.ajax({
              crossOrigin: true,
              proxy: "http://localhost:8888/whorl/proxy.php",
              url: url,
              //dataType: "json", //no need. if you use crossOrigin, the dataType will be override with "json"
              //charset: 'ISO-8859-1', //use it to define the charset of the target url
              context: {},
              success: function(data) {
                  //alert(data);
                  var body = data; 
                  console.log(body.length);
                  //body/data is a string
                  var text = body.split(' ') , chunk;
                  console.log(text.length);

                   var length = text.length - 10;
                            var increment = function(array) {
                            while (array.length > length) {

                    var chunk = array.splice(0,10).join(" ");
                      $( '#test' ).html(chunk).append('<button id="button">next</button>');
                      console.log(chunk)
                            }
                        }

    // need a function that starts at i 0-10 and adds the next 10 indexes every time the button is clicked
            $(document).ready(function(){
            $("button").click(function() {
              increment(text);

            });
    });
      }
            })
            .done(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
                //alert(data);
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give only the increment function (plus some hints):

```
var increment = function(array) {
    if (array.chunk < array.length) {
        var chunk = array.slice(array.chunk,Math.min(array.chunk+array.chunkSize, array.length).join(" ");
        array.chunk += array.chunkSize;
        $( '#test' ).append(' ' + chunk);
        console.log(chunk);
    }
};
```

**Note** the increment function will only append the **next** chunk and **not** the whole text **uo to** the current chunk. So this is different than your original application. To maintain the functionality, place the next button in another container like this:

```
<div id="test"></div>
<button id="button">next</button>
```

The actual text will be appended chunk-by-chunk inside the `div#test`

The function uses a trick that maintains information about current chunk in the array itself.

Use like this:

```
var text = body.split(' ');
text.chunk = 0; text.chunkSize = 10;
```

if you want to rewind the array (hypothetical case), you can do:

```
text.chunk = 0;
```

Comment: Thank you, but when I try the solution the ajax fails. Why would that happen?

Comment: @Mickey, i dont know was it working before? Make sure no missing/superflous commas/semicolons are there. For example when adding the `text.chunk = 0; text.chunkSize = 10;` code in your code

Comment: Yes, when I comment out the solution it works again. And okay I'll look it over!

Comment: @Mickey, note updated answer to suit your original application but using `append` instead of `html`

Comment: Nvm solved it by changing var chunk to:      var slice = array.slice(array.chunk,Math.min(array.chunk+array.chunkSize, array.length));
                           var chunk = slice.join(" ");

Comment: One more question. I created a previous button, took the increment function copied it, called it decrement and changed all the + to - and I swear it was working but I did something and now text just disappears when prev is pressed.

Comment: @Mickey, no this will not work to make a decrement function, since it will have to start from the whole array i.e  `text.chunk = text.length-1` and work backwards, but at the same time, *removing content* from the `div#test` container instead of *appending* it. So it is a little trickier